# Cómo saber desde python si una ventana Windows está visible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como sabemos, el iniciar un proceso/programa 
Con

`os.startfile()`

O

`Popen()`

¿Este se inicia en el sistema, pero como saber si la interfaz del mismo está lista para poder interactuar con el programa en cuestión?

Answer (score 0):

esta cuestión creo que está respondida en el foro de stackoverflow de la comunidad inglesa:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python

traducción respuesta:

En windows, tu puedes usar las extensiónes de windows para python
(http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/):

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
print GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
```

(encontré esto en http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/programmer/active-window-logger/)

no sabes si una ventana está activa pero si si está siendo usada por lo que si está siendo usada significa que está visible

Comment: Lo logre....
Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda